# "blieben" und "bleiben würden"

Tags: grammar

Was sollte ich im folgenden Satz besser verwenden?

> Mit dem Erhalt der Förderung möchte ich auch meine Chancen auf berufliche Positionen verbessern, die mir ohne diese Förderung eventuell verwehrt blieben.

Ist "verwehrt blieben" korrekt, oder sollte es besser "bleiben würden" lauten?

Comment: Für mich hört sich "blieben" deutlich besser an, vermutlich weil "verwehrt bleiben" ohnehin schon zwei Wörter sind, oder auch weil man auf jeden Fall "verwehrt wären" statt "verwehrt sein würden" sagen würde.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es geht in der Fragestellung darum, ob der Konjunktiv II mit "würde"-Ersatzform gebildet werden sollte oder nicht.

Beide Formen sind im Deutschen zulässig und korrekt. Es ist mehr oder weniger eine Frage des Stils. Im geschriebenen Deutsch sind heute beide Formen gängig. Es könnte sein, dass die vom  Präteritum Indikativ des Verbs abgeleitete Forme ("bliebe") umgangssprachlich vielleicht individuell als zu hochgestochen empfunden werden könnte.

Ich persönlich finde die Version mit *blieben* für den Text oben durchaus angemessen.

Als Ergänzung füge ich hier [diesen Auszug über den Konjunktiv des deutschen Wikipedia-Artikel (Grammatik)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Konjunktiv) an:

> [...] Viele alte Konjunktivformen [wurden] durch die „Würde-Form“ verdrängt, insbesondere bei:
>
> - formaler Gleichheit von Konjunktiv- und Indikativform (Konjunktiv II der schwachen Verben)
>     „ich sagte“ (Indikativ = Konjunktiv) → „ich würde sagen“
> - Vorhandensein paralleler und/oder veralteter Formen des Konjunktivs II
>     „ich wärfe“ ↔ „ich würfe“ → „ich würde werfen“
>
> (Die veralteten Konjunktiv-II-Formen gehen auf veraltete Präteritumformen dieser Verben zurück.) Am stärksten halten sich synthetische Konjunktivformen noch bei solchen starken Verben, bei denen der Konjunktiv II durch Umlautung noch in allen Personen zweifelsfrei zu erkennen ist (z. B. ich käme, du käm(e)st, er käme usw.).
>
> Der Status der „Würde-Form“ ist in der Sprachwissenschaft umstritten. Während ihn manche als allzu „volkstümlich“ ablehnen und nur sehr begrenzt akzeptieren; betrachten ihn andere als „Nebenform“ (innerhalb des Konjunktivs II) und wiederum andere als eigenständige „moderne Form“, die Schritt für Schritt die alten Formen (bis auf feste Wendungen) ersetzen wird. Ähnliches vollzog und/oder vollzieht sich z. B. in den Schwestersprachen des Deutschen, dem Dänischen und Englischen.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm - ich würde sagen: korrekt ist beides, die Formulierung "bleiben würden" ist aber "schwächer" als "blieben". Schwächer nicht im Sinne von weniger tauglich, aber weniger stark. "bleiben würden" beschreibt die Chancen, als ob sie fern lägen. Die Formulierung "werden" lässt m.E. darauf schließen, dass der Sprecher selber nur eine Vermutung äußert. Dazu kommt noch die Relativierung durch das "eventuell" und durch das "wollen" ("Ich möchte..." statt "Ich verbessere...").

Ich schlage vor, strategisch an die Sache heranzugehen: Wenn ich davon ausgehe, dass mir Chancen verwehrt bleiben, würde ich das so ausdrücken. Dann muss die Gegenseite, wenn sie anderer Ansicht ist, argumentieren. Stelle ich es nur als Wahrscheinlichkeit dar, muss die Gegenseite nur den Grad der Wahrscheinlichkeit bestreiten. Konkret: "Och nee, so schlimm ist das nicht, Ihre Chancen mindern sich keineswegs!". Hat man sich bereits durch die Formulierung mit "werden" und durch das Eingeständnis, dass die Folgen nur eventuell eintreten, auf den Rückzug begeben, kann man das nicht mehr ohne weiteres bestreiten. Man diskutiert also von vornherein auf einer anderen Ebene.

Also:

> Erhalte ich die Förderung [besser Verbal- als Nominalstil], verbessert dies meine Chancen auf [berufliche Positionen  - besser konkret formulieren - welche Positionen genau?], die mir ohne diesen Titel verwehrt blieben.